# What is H.450.2? What happens when it doesn't exist?

Tags: linux, protocols, network-protocols, voip

What is [H.450.2](http://www.protocols.com/pbook/h323.htm#H4502)?

I noticed that many applications such as Ekiga for linux/windows allowes this. But many others does not, as a result i see some problems which confusing me and having no answer to move forward. But i am not sure what it has to do for call scenarios as following:

```
Endpoint 1 <-------> (H.323 gatekeeper) <------> Endpoint 2
                           |
                Administrator remotely place an call 
              (root@gw~$ makecall endpoint1 endpoint2)
```

Gatekeeper have registered users 1 and 2. From the gatekeeper action is triggered to connect user 1/2. If user 1 and user 2 has no H.450.2 protocol support or built in, can gatekeeper send call signal to them?  However User1 can dial to User2, and gatekeeper gets call signal.

Thanks for your advise

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: @Gade: Yes, i am testing a softphone source code written in C++/Java, which confusing me with this theory.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you concluded that H.450.2 exists?  Where do you see this protocol?  Is there some text debugging output we can look at?

Comment: @Mike Pennington: Please see above.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what problems are confusing you?  It is difficult to help right now with so little evidence of the problem you are attempting to solve

Comment: @Mike Pennington: Gatekeeper have registered users 1 and 2. From the gatekeeper action is triggered to connect user 1/2. If user 1 and user 2 has no H.450.2 protocol support or built in. Can gatekeeper send call signal to them? But however User1 can dial to User2, and gatekeeper gets call signal.

Comment: Thank you for the details; I will consider this after work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most commercial hardwares does not shift with such functionality H.450.2. Your better chances are using GnuGK or build your own message protocol to do hardware codec to codec.

Thank you